# PHP restrict access to direct request to html content

Tags: php, .htaccess

First i use basic php only (no framework here).

What i want to do is :

1. Restrict Access to some PHP pages
2. Keep a good separation between my html files and my php files with logic.

I have done something but we could do better. So i'd like to knwow your advices .

**1. Here is my PHP file:**

```
    <?php
session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=“Test restricted area”');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        print file_get_contents("views/mypage.html");
    }

?>
```

**2. mypage.html is nothing else than pure html**

```
<html>
<div><span>mapage</div></span>
</html>
```

**3. And direct access to "view/mypage.html" is protected by htaccess**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require user
```

It works !!! but can we do better ?

Thanks

Comment: Place views folder outside webroot, then only php can access them. No need for htaccess